# How to add the values of key 1 into another key inside the dictionary to build up an array?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, key-value-store

For example I have a dictionary 1:

`dict1 = {"a":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 6], "b":[1, 4, 6, 0], "c":[4, 6, 7, 8, 0, 9]}`

and I want to create a new array like this:

`array = [5, 10, 13, 8, 0, 10, 3, 6]`

which each index inside the new array is the sum of the same position in each key in the dictionary.

Comment: Show what you tried to solve this problem as properly formatted code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `zip()` is the normal way to match up items like this. However, `zip()` will stop at the shortest element you are zipping, so you won't get all the values you want. For this, you can use [`itertools.zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) with a `fillvalue` or `0`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

dict1 = {"a":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 6], "b":[1, 4, 6, 0], "c":[4, 6, 7, 8, 0, 9]}

[sum(nums) for nums in zip_longest(*dict1.values(), fillvalue=0)]
# [5, 10, 13, 8, 0, 10, 3, 6]
```

Comment: thanks! This solves my questions! Just one more question, what does the fillvalue do in this function?

Comment: @TravisTeo, when you don't have lists of equal length you need to tell it what to use for the lists that ran out of values. That's what the `fillvalue` does. Best way to understand is probably to print: `list(zip_longest(*dict1.values(), fillvalue=0))`